# Trac Standalone Permissions

Tags: trac, alpine-linux

I'm running tracd on Docker with Alpine. I'm able to get it running and can access all components except I can't login. I'm running this script on docker run:

```
if [ -f /trac/VERSION ]; then
    echo "Project already exists here"
else
    echo "Creating a new project"
    trac-admin /trac initenv $projectname sqlite:db/trac.db
    echo "Setting permissions for $user"
    trac-admin /trac permission add $user $password
    htpasswd -bc /trac/.htpasswd $user $password
fi

tracd --port 8000 --basic-auth="$projectname,/trac/.htpasswd,trac" /trac
```

This script completes without any errors and brings up the web server:

```
Server starting in PID 15.
Serving on 0.0.0.0:8000 view at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using HTTP/1.1 protocol version
192.168.1.133 - - [12/May/2017 20:05:37] "GET /trac HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But when I go to http://myserver:8000/trac I'm not prompted for a password nor do I see an admin user tab.

$user and $password have the default vaulues of admin/admin but can be overriden at runtime. I've verified that .htpassword is where it should be, though I would expect an error if it were not there.

Listing permissions on the existing project does return appropriately. Here's the first of them:

```
docker exec -it trac trac-admin /trac permission list 

User   Action
----------------------
admin  BROWSER_VIEW
admin  CHANGESET_VIEW
admin  FILE_VIEW
```

When attempting to login in Trac I get the following error:

```
Trac Error
Authentication information not available. Please refer to the installation documentation.
```

**How can I get authentication working with Tracd?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grant `TRAC_ADMIN` to `$user`, you'll need to change this line:

`- trac-admin /trac permission add $user $password
    + trac-admin /trac permission add $user TRAC_ADMIN`

To get authentication working, make this change:

    `- tracd --port 8000 --basic-auth="$projectname,/trac/.htpasswd,trac" /trac
    + tracd --port 8000 --basic-auth="trac,/trac/.htpasswd,trac" /trac`

The first argument to `--basic-auth` needs to be the name of your environment directory.